# How do I use monospace fonts on the BlackBerry?

Tags: java, blackberry, java-me, fonts

On Blackberry OS 4.5 and up, how do I select a monospace font from within a java app?

I have read the docs, but the only thing that references "mono" *anything* is a bitmap font.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just had a look on a number of devices (using the options screens) for mono space fonts. There does not appear to be any way to select a mono spaced FontFamily through the API, other than by name, also not all OS versions seem to have mono space FontFamilies installed:

9800 V6.0.0.246 - Andale Mono

9700 V5.0.0.862 - None

8820 V4.2.2.169 - None (I know it is earlier than your preferance).

If you really need to use a mono spaced font, you may wish to consider installing one. There is a description of how to do this on [eHow](http://www.ehow.com/how_5888325_install-new-font-blackberry.html), though I haven't tried this myself. Do be careful of how much memory you are using though.

Comment: Thanks a lot! It was how it seemed to me, but I didn't want to believe it was true. Thanks again.